# What’s wrong with this code to reverse a string, if swap fuction is created without using the "temp" variable?

Tags: c, string

```
/*implementation of strrev i.e. string reverse function*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

/*length of the string i.e. cells in the string*/
static const unsigned int MAX_LENGTH = 100;
//static const int MAX_LENGTH = -100;

/*reverses the string*/
void reverseString(char[]);
/*swaps the elements in the cells of a string*/
void swap(char[], int, int);

/*runs the program*/
int main()
{
    char string[MAX_LENGTH];
    //char string[0];  //no error!
    //char string[-1]; //error! 

    gets(string);
    reverseString(string);
    printf("\n%s", string);

    return 0;
}

void reverseString(char string[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < (strlen(string) / 2); i++)
    //for(i = 0; i <= ((strlen(string) - 1) / 2); i++)
    {
        swap(string, i, (strlen(string) - 1 - i));
    }
}

void swap(char string[], int i, int j)
{
    int temp = string[i];
    string[i] = string[j];
    string[j] = temp;
    /*     
    string[i] = string[i] + string[j];  //i = i + j
    string[j] = string[i] - string[j];  //j = i + j - j = i
    string[i] = string[i] - string[j];  //i = i + j - i = j
    */
}
```

Look at the "reverseString" and "swap" functions. The current code works perfectly. If the swap function is rewritten by using no "temp" variable, code still runs smoothly.

However if the "for" line in "reverseString" function is replaced with the code just below it (commented using single-line comment), the code doesn't work for single character strings if modified swap function (without temp) is used, but works if original swap function (with temp) is used.

Why is this behavior seen?

Comment: Cause `i < n/2` is different from `i <= (n-1)/2`. Maybe you meant `i <= n/2-1`?

Comment: <O/T> use [`fgets`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead of `gets`

Comment: That's a perfect opportunity to start learning how to use your debugger.

Comment: You need to master the art of debugging programs. There is a wonderful tutorial out there, which will teach you this invaluable skill: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to call `strlen` twice per iteration over the string...? Why not just `int i=0, j=strlen(string) - 1; for(; i<j; ++i,--j){ swap(...); }`

Comment: @CiaPan I wanted my code to be readable to beginners. I will consider your recommendation if I dive into competitive coding. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of the swap function without a temp depends on the two indexes being different from each other.

Suppose `i` and `j` are the same.  You then effectively have the following:

```
string[i] = string[i] + string[i];  // string[i] is now 2 * string[i]
string[i] = string[i] - string[i];  // string[i] is now always 0
string[i] = string[i] - string[i];  // still 0
```

So swapping an element with itself will zero it out.

Now looking at the loop in `reverseString` when you use `i < (strlen(string) / 2)` as your condition.  If the length of the string is odd, the loop stops before reaching the middle element, so swapping an element with itself doesn't happen.

But when `i <= ((strlen(string) - 1) / 2)` is your condition, the loop *does* operate on the middle element which subsequently gets swapped with itself and gets zeroed out.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest less `strlen` calls. Your code it IMO too complicated

```
char *reverse(char *str) 
{
    char *saved = str;
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char *end = str + len - 1; 

    for(size_t index = 0; index < len / 2; index++)
    {
        char tmp = *str;
        *str++ = *end;
        *end -- = tmp;
    }
    return saved; 
}
```

or

```
char *reverse1(char *str)
{
    char *saved = str;
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char *end = str + len - 1; 

    while(str < end)
    {
        char tmp = *str;
        *str++ = *end;
        *end -- = tmp;
    }
    return saved;
}
```

why to return `char *` instead of `void`. it allows you yo use the functions directly in another operations. For example:

```
char str[] = "Hello World";

printf("%s\n", reverse(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you cannot use this code:

```
string[i] = string[i] + string[j];  //i = i + j
string[j] = string[i] - string[j];  //j = i + j - j = i
string[i] = string[i] - string[j];  //i = i + j - i = j
```

to swap the value of the variable with itself, since it's the same variable, not two different variables, and the value gets overwritten.

I would strongly recommend you start using C++, and use `std::swap()` every time you need something to be swapped =)

Comment: the language in the question is `C`. Although I agree with you that C++ makes your life easier (until it doesn't) , suggesting to change the language is a little presumptuous. There are perfectly valid applications for the `C` language where changing the language itself is not practical or blatantly impossible.